# Non-blocking, unbound, efficient 1 writer 1 reader Queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I am attempting to write an efficient queue with one thread inserting elements and one thread reading them. I decided to write it as circular list of blocks, where each block contains an array of elements. To preserve efficiency I tried to avoid atomic variables and locks. 
I am having trouble of finding a reason why during testing my queue eventually reaches a state when an element returned is not an expected element.

I tested this with integers. Inserting them in order with one thread. The second thread checks whether the queue is empty and if not, reads an element and checks its value agains an expected value.

I read much about memory barriers and instruction reordering caused by compiler optimalizations but I still can't wrap my head around why it is still not working.

I will greatly appreciate any suggestions. The code consists of 2 classes a node and a queue.

```
template<typename T> class node {
public:
  T *data = nullptr;
  unsigned int size = 0;
  volatile node *volatile next = nullptr;

  volatile int reader = 0;
  volatile int writer = 0;

  node(unsigned int size = 64) : size(size) {
      data = new T[size];
  }

  ~node() {
      delete[] data;
  }

  bool enqueue(T value) volatile {
      if (writer < reader) {
          return false;
      }
      data[writer] = value;
      writer = (writer + 1) % size;
      return true;
  }

  bool dequeue(T &value) volatile {
      value = data[reader];
      reader = (reader + 1) % size;
      return true;
  }

  // must be called before every dequeue
  bool empty() volatile {
      return reader == writer;
  }
}; // scroll further down

template <typename U> class queue {
  volatile node<U> *volatile reader;
  volatile node<U> *volatile writer;
public:
  queue() {
      writer = new node<U>();
      writer->next = writer;
      reader = writer;

      volatile node<U> *volatile tmp = writer;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          tmp->next = new node<U>();
          tmp = tmp->next;
      }
      tmp->next = writer;
  }

  ~queue() {

  }

  void enqueue(U value) volatile {
      if (!writer->enqueue(value)) {
          if (writer->next != reader && writer->next->empty()) {
              writer = writer->next;
              writer->enqueue(value);
          } else {
              node<U> *volatile n = new node<U>();
              n->next = writer->next;;
              writer->next = n;
              writer = writer->next;
              writer->enqueue(value);
          }
      }
  }

  U dequeue() volatile {
      U val;
      while (true) {
          if (!reader->empty() && reader->dequeue(val)) {
              return val;
          } else {
              reader = reader->next;
          }
      }
  }

  bool empty() volatile {
      return reader == writer && reader->empty();
  }
};
```

Comment: `volatile` doesn't help for these kind of problems.

Comment: You will need to use some synchronization: reading an object written in another thread without synchronization  is undefined behavior. `volatile` does not yield synchronization.